# Solving an equation with high powers in Python

Tags: python, sympy

How to calculate a one-unknown equation that has exponentiation with a high exponent?

I try to use SymPy solveset, but I am getting an error:

> mpmath.libmp.libhyper.NoConvergence: convergence to root failed; try n < 15 or maxsteps > 50

```
from __future__ import division
from sympy import *

n = Symbol('n', real=True, positive=True)
d = Symbol('d', real=True, positive=True)
i = Symbol('i', real=True, positive=True)
o = Symbol('o', real=True, positive=True)
z = Symbol('z', real=True, positive=True)
eq_left = Symbol('eq_left', real=True, positive=True)
eq_right = Symbol('eq_right', real=True, positive=True)

d = 100
i = 0.0001
o = 0.0001

eq_left = (1 + d*(z/n))**n
eq_right = (1 + d*(z/(n+1)))**(n+1)*(1-d*i)*(1-d*o)

for every in range(1, 41):
  n = every
  results = solveset(Eq(eq_left, eq_right), z, domain=S.Reals)
  print(results)
```

My only unknown is "z" variable and I need to calculate it for the changing "n" variable, which is a power in range even to 40, but near 12 I am getting mentioned error.

1. How can I resolve this equation using such a high exponentation?
2. The second issue is performance. For ever higher powers, the computation time is getting longer. My guess is the solveset function would count an exponent of 40 for an hour.

Comment: Have you tried to solve the logarithm of the equation instead ?

Comment: @manu190466 I have not used logarithms before to transform an equation of this kind. Could you please indicate any source with an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly just writing `n = every` won't substitute the value for `n` in the equation. Also there's no point in making symbols if you are only going to reassign the variables to numbers.

Next an issue with finding the roots of high degree polynomials is that it can be numerically ill-conditioned (see e.g. Wilkinson's polynomial) so floating point solvers can fail (the problem you are seeing) or can return inaccurate results.

SymPy has a function `real_roots` that will calculate the roots for you using exact rational arithmetic so that it will always succeed but you should be aware that the higher the degree thee slower it can be. Here is how you could use it in your problem:

```py
from sympy import *

n = Symbol('n', real=True, positive=True)
z = Symbol('z', real=True, positive=True)

d = 100
i = 0.0001
o = 0.0001

eq_left = (1 + d*(z/n))**n
eq_right = (1 + d*(z/(n+1)))**(n+1)*(1-d*i)*(1-d*o)

for every in range(1, 41):
  eq = Eq(eq_left, eq_right).subs(n, every)
  results = [r.n(3) for r in real_roots(eq)]
  print()
  print('n =', every)
  pprint(eq)
  print(results)
```

This will output e.g.:

```
n = 1
                             2
100⋅z + 1 = 0.9801⋅(50⋅z + 1) 
[-0.00247, 0.00328]

n = 2
                                3
          2          ⎛100⋅z    ⎞ 
(50⋅z + 1)  = 0.9801⋅⎜───── + 1⎟ 
                     ⎝  3      ⎠ 
[-0.0225, -0.00431, 0.00566]

n = 3
           3                     
⎛100⋅z    ⎞                     4
⎜───── + 1⎟  = 0.9801⋅(25⋅z + 1) 
⎝  3      ⎠                      
[-0.00610, 0.00800]

n = 4
          4                    5
(25⋅z + 1)  = 0.9801⋅(20⋅z + 1) 
[-0.0433, -0.00788, 0.0103]

... (skip to end)

n = 40
         40                     41
⎛5⋅z    ⎞            ⎛100⋅z    ⎞  
⎜─── + 1⎟   = 0.9801⋅⎜───── + 1⎟  
⎝ 2     ⎠            ⎝  41     ⎠  
[-0.167, -0.0714, 0.0934]
```

Taking `n = 50` this method takes about 20 seconds on this machine to isolate the roots and then about 100 milliseconds to evaluate them numerically (note that it is likely to be a lot slower if `gmpy2` is not installed):

```
In [14]: eq = Eq(eq_left, eq_right).subs(n, 50)

In [15]: %time rs = real_roots(eq)
CPU times: user 18.2 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 18.2 s
Wall time: 18.2 s

In [16]: %time [r.n(3) for r in rs]
CPU times: user 132 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 132 ms
Wall time: 133 ms
Out[16]: [-0.762, -0.413, -0.172, -0.0891, 0.116]
```

A faster but less accurate way to do this is to get the coefficients of the polynomial and use numpy's `np.roots` function to compute the roots:

```
In [18]: %time np.roots(coeffs)
CPU times: user 4 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 4 ms
Wall time: 15 ms
Out[18]: 
array([-1.37492117+0.08492563j, -1.37492117-0.08492563j,
       -1.34230104+0.27325799j, -1.34230104-0.27325799j,
       -1.24357613+0.44751152j, -1.24357613-0.44751152j,
       -1.10133737+0.57490763j, -1.10133737-0.57490763j,
       -0.94102825+0.65104599j, -0.94102825-0.65104599j,
       -0.77947722+0.68005214j, -0.77947722-0.68005214j,
       -0.63061961+0.66983363j, -0.63061961-0.66983363j,
       -0.50498567+0.63165257j, -0.50498567-0.63165257j,
       -0.66383269+0.4140557j , -0.66383269-0.4140557j ,
       -0.40666124+0.57606007j, -0.40666124-0.57606007j,
       -0.33397587+0.51025345j, -0.33397587-0.51025345j,
       -0.32238493+0.45018494j, -0.32238493-0.45018494j,
       -0.25946166+0.44483862j, -0.25946166-0.44483862j,
       -0.4604639 +0.31887167j, -0.4604639 -0.31887167j,
       -0.52897048+0.14733357j, -0.52897048-0.14733357j,
       -0.51901322+0.j        , -0.20469413+0.39709201j,
       -0.20469413-0.39709201j, -0.16115441+0.34433415j,
       -0.16115441-0.34433415j, -0.128326  +0.28740561j,
       -0.128326  -0.28740561j,  0.11640516+0.j        ,
       -0.10690522+0.22907772j, -0.10690522-0.22907772j,
       -0.27405046+0.j        , -0.09641536+0.17292539j,
       -0.09641536-0.17292539j, -0.0942632 +0.12248766j,
       -0.0942632 -0.12248766j, -0.09570453+0.0792701j ,
       -0.09570453-0.0792701j , -0.09593393+0.0416225j ,
       -0.09593393-0.0416225j , -0.08898598+0.00827996j,
       -0.08898598-0.00827996j])
```

While the `np.roots` function is faster you can see that it is less accurate and in fact it cannot always tell if the root is real. It does however succeed in this case to get a reasonably accurate representation of the unique positive root giving

```
In [23]: np.roots(coeffs)[37]
Out[23]: (0.11640516183685487+0j)
```

You can calculate this root more accurately using SymPy to see the error:

```
In [24]: rs[-1].n(100)
Out[24]: 
0.1164051614564151717584154914217696566950672923231091599568569989915689653109680620577952876340247
917
```

This shows that `np.roots` gives about 9 accurate decimal digits in this case. Note though that if you make the polynomial higher degree or lower degree but worse conditioned then it is possible that `np.roots` will not give any accurate digits at all (try Wilkinson's polynomial with higher and higher degree).

So you have a choice between `real_roots` which is guaranteed to work for any polynomial with rational coefficients but can be slow for high degrees and `np.roots` which is faster because it does not use exact arithmetic but does not necessarily have any guaranteed accuracy.

On the other hand if you are only interested in the unique real root of these polynomials then you can use general root-finding algorithms rather then just those used for polynomials. In that case just the bisection method is sufficient but it probably needs to be done with exact or arbitrary precision arithmetic to succeed in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the logarithm of the equation

```
f(z)=n*log(1+d*z/n) - (n+1)*log(1+d*z/(n+1)) - log(1-d*i)-log(1-d*o)
```

and the first terms of the Taylor expansion of the logarithm around 1 gives

```
d*z-0.5*(d*z)**2/n - d*z+0.5*(d*z)**2/(n+1) = -d*i-0.5*(d*i)**2 - d*o-0.5*(d*o)**2

z**2 = (2*(i+o)+d*(i**2+o**2))*n*(n+1)/d
```

The positive square root should give a good enough approximation of the positive solution so that a few Newton or secant iterates should converge to the exact value in the desired precision. Or use `scipy.optimize.find_root` or `fsolve` with this initial guess. For very large values of `n` it might increase the accuracy when using the `log1p` function in the first two terms, or use other measures to more directly reduce cancellation errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to learn how to use logarithms for future transformations